# View issues that are assigned to me?

Tags: github

I've checked the GitHub docs but can't find this. I've also googled this but can't find an answer.

How can I see all issues for all my repositories that have been assigned to me on the GitHub website?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for https://github.com/issues/assigned.

The easiest way to get there is to click on the **Issues** link at the top right of the GitHub UI, and then the **Assigned** tab at the left side of the screen:

[image: GitHub Issues]

You can also use the `assignee` key in the search bar manually, e.g. `assignee:panthro`.

Answer (score 5):

6 years later (January 2020), you also have the `@me` search syntax.

See "[Search by `@me`](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-01-20-search-by-me/)"

That means [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris)' [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26381889/6309) of the "`Issues`" search field would now read:

```
state:open is:issue assignee:@me
```

No need for "`assignee:myuser`"