# How to find issues that had been assigned to me in the past?

Tags: github, issue-tracking

I want to list all issues I've been working on recently, that is - had been assigned to. I've done a lot and reassigned them to QA team.

How do I find them now?

They are no longer assigned to me, so I can't just [View issues that are assigned to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381183/view-issues-that-are-assigned-to-me)

Comment: Do you want a web (i.e. UI solution), or would a query which gives this information also be sufficient?

Comment: Anything will do. Can't an arbitrary query can be entered in issue search field?

Comment: In the search issues box on GitHub, try typing this `assignee:username`, where `username` is your GitHub username.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, only issues currently assigned to me are shown when  I try that.